# New java.security.AccessControlException in Java 8

Tags: java, security, sockets

Previously working network code is throwing `java.security.AccessControlException`
in a fully sandboxed Java `applet`.

```
Can't get socket 2255: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "50.31.1.13:2255" "connect,resolve")
```

What has Oracle changed - what new security hoop must be jumped to
keep sockets to working?

This worked/works in Java 1.7.0_55 and all previous versions of java.

Comment: What is the specific piece of code throwing the exception?

Comment: A partial workaround is to change the applet permissions from sandbox to all-permissions.  The warnings the client has to click through are only a little more scary.

Answer (score 11):

This has indeed changed… From the documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/enhancements-8.html

> - For sandbox RIAs, `URLPermission` is now used to allow connections back to the server from which they were started. `URLPermissions` is granted based on protocol, host and port of the code source. This change has the following implications:
>
>   - For sandbox RIAs, `SocketPermissions` for the origin host is no longer granted. Calls from JavaScript code to the RIA are not granted `SocketPermissions` beginning with JDK 8.
>
>   …

In other words, you cannot create a new `Socket` in a sandbox anymore. You can only create a `URL` using the same host, *same port*, and *same protocol* as the codebase from a fully sandboxed applet then.

Unless Oracle changes its mind, there is no way for a sandboxed applet to get around this (otherwise it would render the entire security concept broken).

Comment: God knows why this new downgrade in applet capabilities was hidden in the "enhancements" section. Sandbox RIAs loaded from a server on a specific port using either the HTTP or HTTPS protocol are not allowed to connect back to a different port on the server. For example, if the RIA is started from https://www.example.com:80, then the RIA is not allowed to connect back to https://www.example.com:8888.

Comment: Most likely because they don’t have a “Downgrade” section and won’t ever create one. It seems that they overreact on security issues after they had that negative press in the past. Breaking things that worked for almost twenty years should be handled with more care and should never be done without providing an alternative… (imho)

Comment: This seems a terrible change. Is there a bug report/petition anywhere asking for this to be reversed?

Comment: @Richard Kennard: Not that I know of. But you may search yourself as I’m not constantly monitoring the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me it sounds like Oracle decided to strengthen the applets security requirements. Here is what I found on [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/548799/Applets/java/Socket-Permissions-Java-applet-Windows):

Make `SecurityManager` accept socket-related permission checks:

```
System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(new SocketPermission("50.31.1.13:2255", "accept, connect, listen"));
//I used IP address from your exception
```

Now, thread-related checks:

```
System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("readerThread"));
```

These lines should be put in the beginning of `main()` method.

The second thing needs to be done is signing your `jar/war/ear` file. First, create a keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias philip -keystore keystore
```

Now, put the signed by CA in your truststore certificate to it or create self-signed certificate:

```
keytool -selfcert -alias philip -keystore keystore
```

And finally, sign the file:

```
jarsigner -keystore keystore -signedjar WhatYouWantTheSignedJarToBeNamed.jar ThePreviousJARYouCreated.jar philip
```

Actually for signed `JAR` file the `SecurityManager`-related magic might be an overhead, but in my opinion it is safer to do both.

Also be advised that sometimes you may need to sign external `jar`s, not only the `jar` where your applet resides.

Comment: the jars in question are fully signed, which was required by a previous security tightening.   This new complaint applies to SANDBOXED applets, which previously did not require any special permission dances to connect to the download server.

Comment: @ddyer ok, maybe obvious, but still: Oracle says applet can connect only to the host it came from. Is 50.31.1.13 the same host?

Comment: Absolutely.  This glitch is breaking at least 3 sites that are currently working with java 1.7.0_55

Comment: @ddyer well.. maybe some issue with determining whether the host is really the same. Is it possible to use domain name? Is there any suspicious DNS server or NAT between the jvm with applet and the server?

Comment: the underlying code does use the domain name, and there is nothing unusual about the server or client.  It's all been working for years.

Comment: out of ideas then :( maybe you can post the piece of applet code?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Your first bit of code is checking for accept permissions. Port numbers available for binding at the local side were restricted in, IIRC, 7u51.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline If this is the issue OP has, I think you should create a separate answer and get the bounty then, as I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev It's not the issue to OP has. What little information we have is that they are having a problem with "connect,resolve" (resolve is implicit). However, your first piece of code checks "accept" as well. (Come to think of it, it may be "listen" that is denied in 7u51.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission in client.policy (for the application client), or in server.policy (for web modules) for the application that needs to set the property. By default, applications only have read permission for properties.

For example, to grant read/write permission for all files in the codebase directory, add or append the following to client.policy or server.policy:

grant codeBase "file:/.../build/sparc_SunOS/sec/-" {
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
 };

Comment: the complaint comes from trying to establish a network connection using sockets.  It has nothing to do with accessing the users machine.  This is new behavior in java 8.