# Unable to Read Images from URL

Tags: java, image, url, io, java-8

I'm unable to read images from URL in Java. Everything was working fine three or four days ago, before I downloaded Eclipse Luna and installed Java 8.

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("some url");
    spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(url);

}catch(IOException e) {

}

System.out.println(spriteSheet);
```

prints out 'null', regardless of what URL I use. My older projects, which were working fine, also encounter the same problem. However, I can read images from files fine. Does anyone know what is going on? Is it a security setting? Thanks.

EDIT:
Sorry! Here's the stack trace:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at Game$Background.<init>(Game.java:50)
at Game.<init>(Game.java:11)
at Game.main(Game.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)null

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Well, let's see... you are catching an exception and not printing the message.  That does not seem to useful. Also, you do you expect to print a BufferedImage to the console?

Comment: Sorry! I edited in the stack trace. BufferedImage can be printed to console with basic information, I believe.

Comment: Provide URL that you try to read

Comment: Any URL gives me the same error.

Comment: I see a `main` method but a `Permission denied` exception. So you have activated a `SecurityManager` manually? Maybe you entered [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23189650/2711488)

Comment: Turns out it was my computer's firewall :P. Sorry to bother the community with such a trivial problem, and thanks to everyone for helping!