# Java Applet stopped working after the upgrade to JRE 8

Tags: java, java-8, applet, policy

We had a applet working properly on JRE 7

After the upgrade to the JRE 8 is stopped working with the error (in the java applet console) `"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied"`.

Adding the below line to the java policy(java.policy) file made it working,

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "ipaddres:port", "connect";
permission java.net.SocketPermission "ipaddress:port", "resolve";
```

Is this the only way to solve this problem, As this cannot be forced to the end users in order to use the applet.

Is there any other alternative scenarios provided to handle these cases.

Comment: You can package your Applet with the JRE8 with that adjustment. That may alleviate having end users to manually change the java.policy

Comment: You didn’t specify the purpose of the socket connection, your Applet tries to open. Without a custom policy file, you can still open `URL` connections to your code base, using the same protocol, but not arbitrary sockets anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23342702/2711488

Comment: @Holger My socket connection use to post the XML to the port 3500 and get the XML response and do the processing to display in the applet

Comment: @ryekayo Does packaging required to refer a local policy file in the java code ?

Comment: @Aravind packaging the JRE will allow your code to run off of it as opposed to using the endusers JRE. With that being said, you can possibly modify the java.policy in a packaged JRE and ship it off with your software. However, you may need to pay Oracle for shipping software with a JRE since they own it...

Comment: @ryekayo *"packaging the JRE will allow your code to run off of it as opposed to using the endusers JRE..."* Not with applets, it won't. A (user installed) JRE must be present before anything it possible with applets, then there is no option to switch to another JRE (e.g. as supplied by the developer / deployer).